# Embedding of list of objects

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec, embeddings, representation

I have a dataset where each sample is a list of ordered items, lets say grocery list ,  and a label from 6 categories . each list can have up to 120 items but the mean items is 12 items in a list.

i would like to embed each sample in a similar way to word2vec and maybe average the vectors for each list to get 1 vector per sample.

You think that word2vec is the right approach for it ? since the "texts" are very short and the location of each item is not contextual but more like the number purchased

Comment: It depends on whether item order makes sense or not. I wouldn't recommend word2vec if not. I think you should try to perform one-hot encoding of items and apply non-negative matrix factorization, or train an auto-encoder.

Comment: You can also find [StarSpace](https://github.com/facebookresearch/StarSpace) useful

Comment: @roman , the order of the items is amount purchased, you can think of it as ordering the items in a recipe by their size (or weights  or whatever) . i want to create dense vector space of the lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to make embeddings for sequences of items, and order doesn't make much sense. You don't have a specific objective, just want to retrieve embeddings with some conventional properties, such as natural clustering.

If you can train word2vec and take mean of item embeddings in a cart, you'll probably get noisy vectors. It doesn't work as well as expected, from my experience. I suggest that you try dimensionality reduction methods, such as [NMF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html). Fit it with a sparse binary matrix of shape `(num_samples, num_items)`. You'll get transformed vectors of desired dimensionality.

Then you might want to evaluate embeddings somehow. If don't have any quality metrics, you can either perform clustering to see how your embeddings form groups, or make nearest neighbour search queries by hand.

Good luck!

Comment: I have found this blog (https://jaan.io/food2vec-augmented-cooking-machine-intelligence/) which used word2vec method to embed food ingredients in recipes. Aiming to try it as well